# Same page form submit very slow to display data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a Joomla site that I am building a form for. The form is working fine in a localhost test environment but when I put it on my live server, the form would not work properly. I stripped out code until I basically just had the form and I still have issues, the form is very slow to submit and display the data, it could take minutes for the updated data to display and I have to refresh the page to get it. On another server the form works properly. Data is displayed as fast as the submit button is clicked.

I've been fighting this for a couple of days and have gotten nowhere.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
<select name="vendor_num">
    <option value="" selected="selected" > Select a Vendor </option>  
    <option value="000000" >All Vendors</option>
    <option value="008064" >Great Glacier Salmon</option>
    <option value="008173" >Seed 2 Sausage</option>
    <option value="008219" >Back Forth Artisan Cheese</option>
    <option value="008215" >True North Salmon</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="prov_ont">
    <input type="radio" id="prov_ont" name="prov" value="Ontario" > Ontario
</label>
<br />
<label for="country_canada">
    <input type="radio" id="country_canada" name="country" value="Canada" > Canada
</label>
<br />
<label for="kosher">
    <input type="radio" id="kosher_flag" name="kosher" value="Y" > Kosher
</label>
<br />
<label for="halal">
    <input type="radio" id="halal_flag" name="halal" value="Y" > Halal
</label>
<br />
<label for="oceanwise">
    <input type="radio" id="oceanwise_flag" name="oceanwise" value="Y" > Oceanwise 
</label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" style="padding:5px;    margin-top:20px;">
<input type="reset" value="reset" name="reset"  style="padding:5px; margin-top:20px;">
</form>
<pre>
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "<br />";
?>
</pre>
```

the problem URL is: http://findlayfoods.com/search-test

Here is another host with the same page working:

http://glenntooth.com/index.php/form-test

I have also tried with action="", exactly the same thing.

I am admittedly a beginner but have been working on this for a while. Help appreciated.

G

Comment: Are you on a $2/month server? (not meaning any offence but cheap server = slow website)

Comment: I'ts not that slow when I try it... but I don't get any data as well, except some array getting populated when I try All vendors...

Comment: Do you have any debug settings that you can turn on? also, if you could provide the PHP, that would help

Comment: Not slow for me either, and Chrome Dev tools shows no obvious points of latency.

Comment: No as far as I know the server is top notch. I don't have other problems with it. It's confusing.

Comment: I have turned on the Joomla Debug.

Comment: Dad White, not sure what you mean by the php, there is just a bit of php to display the form output.

Comment: I turned on the Debug in my Joomla to maximun and my page generated an error. I turned the Debug back to default and now my page is functioning properly.

Comment: Now I am more confused than before. It might me my hosting provider did something, haven;t heard back from them yet. Thanks for your assistance all. I will come back and let you know if and when I understand what just happened.